# JavaScript: Create RSA keypair from own Entropy

Tags: javascript, jquery, rsa

I want to create a RSA keypair (public/private key) in JavaScript. There are a lot of libraries to do that.

But is there a library which allows me to pass my own entropy (or random bytes) which will be used to create the keypair?